# jquery replicate values in to other area

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

IS there an easy way to replicate values in to other areas

i.e. if i have 2 or 3 select menus or other form fields.

say

```
<select id=first>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>

<select id=second>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>

<div id=firstvalue></div>
<div id=secondvalue></div>
```

If i want the divs html to automatically show the values of the select box, Would I have to do a piece of code for change on either component ?

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the divs to automatically show the selected value of any selectbox you can use the following jQuery:

```
$('#first').change(function(){ 
/* target the first selectbox with id #first and bind a change event to it */

    $('#firstvalue').html($(this).val()); 
    /* set the html of the div with id #firstvalue to the selected option*/

});

/* the same for the second selectbox */
$('#second').change(function(){

    $('#secondvalue').html($(this).val());

});
```

I would recommend changing your HTML though, so the selectboxes that are being handled have the same class and store their target within a `data` attribute. Like so:

**HTML**

```
<select class="show_val" data-target="#value_1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>

<div id="value_1"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.show_val').change(function(){

    $($(this).data('target')).html($(this).val());

}
```

This way you can use the same jQuery event for all selectboxes.

Comment: Well if you're going to just *write* it for him/her... ;-)

Comment: I guess I'm one of those bad teachers :(, added some explanation now so it actually teaches something.

Answer (score 2):

You want one code to work on both? [Try this (example on jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/sfBA3/)

```
$("select").change(function() // retrieve all `select` elements
   {
       // gets the corresponding `div`
       $("div").eq($(this).index())
           .html($(this).val()); // sets the html value of the `div` to
                                 // the selected value on the `select` element
   });
```

[From **jQuery docs**:](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)

- [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)
- [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)
- [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)
- [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 1):

You'd use the `change` event on the select box via the [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) or [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) functions, and in the event handler you'd call the [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function to set the text on the relevant div, getting the value of the selected option via [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) (your `option` elements don't have `value` attributes, so `val` will grab their text instead). In both cases, you look up the elements via the [`$` (or `jQuery`)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) function passing in a CSS selector (e.g., `$("#first")`) for the first select box.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this so you wouldn't have to write code for each select/div:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $('div[id^="' + this.id + '"]').text($(this).val());
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FVGbZ/)

Answer (score 0):

You could also check out [**knockout.js**](http://knockoutjs.com/) and implement the **MVVM** (Model-View-View-Model) pattern, if you're using a JavaScript backing object that is bound to the view/page.

Comment: (P.S. I know you're not really using a backing JavaScript object, but still think it's worthwhile for anyone doing JavaScript to check that out, or similar libraries)